# C++ String memory reuse optimization

Tags: c++, string, performance

I was wondering if string memory for `tmp` can be reuse in below code. Is its memory reallocated in every iteration? Is there any better way to deal with these kind of case?

```
string s, line;
map<string, string> mymap;
while(getline(file, line) {
  if(a) s = "_a";
  else if(b) s = "_b";
  string tmp = line + s;
  mymap.insert(tmp, s);
}
```

Comment: Why not simply declare the string `tmp` outside the `while` loop? It will ensure just one copy of string is reutilized on every iteration.

Comment: "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: Opposite of what rubenvb says. It's all very well someone like Knuth, who deeply understands how his code works, to not care about the answer to a point like this. But people who ignore all details of performance from the start write atrocious C++, and have to spend a lot of time with the profiler where Knuth would solve the same problem "ignoring performance" and it would be fast enough to begin with. He also said, "In established engineering disciplines a 12 % improvement, easily obtained, is never considered marginal and I believe the same viewpoint should prevail in software engineering".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tmp` is created and destroyed each time around the loop, and takes a copy of the string data in `line`. So you can get a cheap probable-improvement-and-can-hardly-be-any-worse like this:

```
if(a) s = "_a";
else if(b) s = "_b";
line += s;
mymap.insert(line, s);
```

I'd also give `s` the type `const char*`: there's not much point assigning a `string` once per loop that only ever contains a copy of a literal. But it does get converted to `string` by the call to `insert`, so there's not much in it either way.

A probable-improvement-and-can-hardly-be-any-worse isn't premature optimization, provided you don't damage your code's simplicity/readability/maintainability/design to achieve it. The larger the scope of `line` and `s`, the more risks there are in playing tricks with them (mutating the value and altering the type, respectively), since you could somehow mislead a reader/maintainer. Which is one of the reasons short functions are good.

In C++11 you could write `mymap.insert(std::move(line), s);` for another easy probable-improvement.

All that said: you might find that no matter how much unnecessary copying and allocation you do, the time taken by that is dwarfed by the time for the I/O in `getline`. In this case there are two very similar ways of writing the code and one of them "should" be more efficient. So you might as well use it, but don't over-value it by thinking it will necessarily make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

Every iteration of the while loop will create and destroy your string `tmp` object. So, the first step is to move `tmp` outside the while loop, as already suggested. That way you don't have to construct a new string object each iteration. But, you still have the `tmp = line + s` assignment which causes memory reallocation each iteration. Using the =operator creates a copy of the arguments, and assigns the copy to the tmp string object. So, the second step is to add the suggested `mymap.insert(line+s, s);` that removes the need for the `tmp` string object.

I think one could continue this improvement some by not assigning `"_a"` or `"_b"` to string `s` every iteration. This could be done once, outside the while loop, and then depending on the contents of `a` and `b` different string objects could be added to your map. Something like this (n.b. this is untested):

```
string a = "_a";
string b = "_b";
string line;
map<string, string> mymap;
while(getline(file, line) {
  if(a) mymap.insert(line+a, a);
  else if(b) mymap.insert(line+b, b);
}
```

One could argue if this is good, in my opinion juanchopanza's answer is enough since it maintains readability of the code. But I think that the code above has fewer copies made.

Comment: You might have changed the meaning of the code, in the case where neither `a` nor `b` evaluates as true. But I'm not sure from the code that the questioner has considered that case either, so you might be fine :-) Btw, in C++03 inserting `line+s` directly reverses any change you might have had from moving `tmp` outside the loop (since it still constructs one temporary object per loop, it's just the temporary doesn't have a name) so I don't think you can claim that they're *both* improvements. In C++11 you should get a move benefit from the actual temporary, which you don't get with `tmp`.

Comment: Instead of inserting line+a you should do line+=a then insert line after the if/else.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, use STD::MOVE semantics which is introduced in C++ 11 standart.

update:
example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string str = "Hello";
    std::vector<std::string> v;

    // uses the push_back(const T&) overload, which means 
    // we'll incur the cost of copying str
    v.push_back(str);
    std::cout << "After copy, str is \"" << str << "\"\n";

    // uses the rvalue reference push_back(T&&) overload, 
    // which means no strings will copied; instead, the contents
    // of str will be moved into the vector.  This is less
    // expensive, but also means str might now be empty.
    v.push_back(std::move(str));
    std::cout << "After move, str is \"" << str << "\"\n";

    std::cout << "The contents of the vector are \"" << v[0]
                                         << "\", \"" << v[1] << "\"\n";
}
```